# Need custom model export script in blender

Tags: python, blender

I've been coding a simple android game with openGL ES 1.0 and require a simple exporter for Blender, but don't really understand python and how to add export scripts to blender 2.59.

I tried the tutorial at: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Advanced_Tutorials/Python_Scripting/Export_scripts , but I couldn't get it working with blender... I tried copying it to the scripts/addons directory but Blender didn't detect it... I tried manually importing it, but nothing happened... I'm thinking it was written for an earlier version.

All I want to write is a simple exporter that exports simple static meshes in a format like the following:

```
// v = vertex, i = indices for polygon, t = uv for vertex
v -1 -1 0
v 1 -1 0
v -1 1 0
v 1 1 0
i 0 1 2
i 1 3 2
t 0 0
t 1 0
t 0 1
t 1 1
```

The tutorial I found made this look really simple, but everything else I found seemed to be more confusing... If anyone could write a quick exporter script for me, I'd be very thankful, or just point me in the right direction... And also how to get it working with Blender 2.59...
Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with Jeff Lamarche's scripts on github.

https://github.com/jlamarche/iOS-OpenGLES-Stuff/tree/master/Blender%20Export

The blog post is here:

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/10/blender-ios.html

I recall having to fiddle with the blender or version tuples in the bl_info dictionary but it has been a while.